# Azure SQL Server - Deleting dates from a table based upon a variable month

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure

I have a table of dates which includes every day as a separate row between a @startDate and an @endDate.

I need to remove all dates apart from the ones which match a @dayOfMonth, say the 16th as an example.

But I don't need to keep every row which contains a 16th of the month. I have to factor in another variable, @everyNMonths. So if @everyNMonths was set to 2, and my @startDate was '2016-10-13' and @endDate was '2017-03-20' I would want to keep:

```
2016-10-16 

2016-12-16

2017-02-16
```

Not sure how I can achieve this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you provide a sample db table structure with data?

Comment: The table just has one column, Date. It has an individual row for every day between '@startDate' and '@endDate'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATE = '2015-11-01'
DECLARE @EndTime DATE = '2016-10-01'
DECLARE @Interval INT = 1
DECLARE @dayOfMonth INT = 16

--CREATE Table #TempTimes

SELECT StartTime
FROM
(
    SELECT StartTime,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) As Num
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT StartTime
        FROM #TempTimes
        WHERE DATEPART(DD,StartTime) = @dayOfMonth
        AND StartTime BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
    )t
)s
WHERE (Num - 1)%@Interval = 0
```